# Getting iOS 8 UIImage Orientation Property

Tags: swift, ios8, uiimage, phasset

I am loading photos from the users Photo roll.

```
    PHImageManager.defaultManager().requestImageForAsset(asset, targetSize:size, contentMode: .AspectFill, options: options)
            {
                result, info in
                //get orientation???
                var image:iImage = iImage(uiimage: result)
                self.selectedPhotoUpdateCallback(editImage,image)
            }
```

However, some times the photos I load are upside down.

I cannot seem to find any information on the meta data for the orientation of these images.

Do you know how I can check the orientation of the requested asset from a PHImageManager?

The picture displays upright when I am selecting from the photo roll, but when I load the full image into another view its rotated (and my code does not apply any rotation).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can get the image orientation via `image.imageOrientation`. Also you can check out this [link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImage_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/UIImageOrientation).